# Nginx syntax problem '~*'

Tags: nginx

I have at condition checking to see if user has a cookie like this:

```
 if ($http_cookie ~* "developer=true" ) {
   ...
 }
```

I'm not familiar with the `~*` syntax, I assume that that means if it 'contains', but what about the opposite? like what if I wanted to check if `$http_cookie` doesn't contain that cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test the variable does not match a regex using `!~` (case sensitive) and `!~*` (case-insensitive) operators:

```
if ($http_cookie !~* "developer=true") {
}
```

By the way, if you want to test a value of cookie named "developer", it would be probably more clear to say:

```
if ($cookie_developer = "true") {
}
```